# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"search-page-list-container"}

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, nosuchelementexception, findelement

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: I have used this url: request_url =
> "https://www.zillow.com/arlington-tx/rentals"

Zillows website link for rental properties being listed{string interpolation} for page #'s
is this url issue? how to put the pages in request_url?

Comment: part1 code:# Zillows website link for rental properties being listed{string interpolation} for page #'s
request_url = "https://www.zillow.com/arlington-tx/rentals"

name = []
details = []
address = []

# Iterating through a range (in reference to the page #'s) and grabbing name,details,address.
for page in range(1,6):
    
    # Formats the zillow's website link with the page num
    base_url = request_url.format(page)

    driver.get(base_url)

Comment: part1 code continue:wait = driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    # Grabs the all the search result element in a page 
    main = driver.find_element_by_id("search-page-list-container")
    
    # Grabs all the info about a listing
    card_info = main.find_elements_by_class_name('list-card-info')
    
    # Iterates through all every listing on the page & appends it all to a list.
    for listing in card_info:
        name.append(listing.find_element_by_class_name('list-card-footer').text)

Comment: part 1code continue:address.append(listing.find_element_by_class_name('list-card-addr').text)
        details.append(listing.find_element_by_class_name('list-card-heading').text)
    
        wait

Comment: Please don't post code or anything like that in comments. [Edit] your question instead